# Bind complex object to cell of DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, binding, datatable

I have a `DataTable` with complex objects.

For example,

```
class ComplexDataWrapper
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    public ComplexData Data{ get; set; }

    public ComplexDataWrapper(ComplexData data)
    {
        this.Data = data;
        this.Name = "Something";
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

And now I want to bind cells from `DataTable` to objects of `ComplexDataWrapper`
So, I try something like this :

```
...
var column = new DataColumn() { ColumnName = columnName, DataType = typeof(ComplexDataWrapper)};
row[column] = new ComplexDataWrapper(data);
```

But, I want to bind for only one property, for example, `Name`.
And in the gridview (`DataTable` is a data source for this view) I want to edit this property(Name).

```
var complexDataWrapper = row[column] as ComplexDataWrapper;
```

complexDataWrapper always equals to NULL.

I know that I miss something.

So my questions : How I can bind my cell of `DataTable` to complex object? Plus in grid view I want to edit exactly one property of complex object.

Thanks. Hopefully, everything is clear.

Comment: so what does your `Data` contain? Does the class initialize properly?

Comment: Also, I assume you're displaying this on a datagrid. Have you considered binding Directly to the DataGrid?

Comment: I'm using DevExpress's BandedGridView to display data from DataTable. Thus DataTable binding to BandedGridView

Comment: Where does the data originate from?  Seems like you are squeezing in one more wrapper than is needed.

Comment: Have you considered using Entity Framework? I think this might line up better with your desire to map "complex" classes to a database.

Answer (score 3):

> So my questions : How I can bind my cell of DataTable to complex object? Plus in grid view I want to edit exactly one property of complex object.

What you need here is the ability to bind to a so called **property path** (e.g. `obj.Prop1.Prop2`). Unfortunately WinForms has limited support for that - it's supported for **simple** data binding (like `control.DataBindings.Add(...)`) but not for **list** data binding which is used by `DataGridView` control and similar.

Fortunately it's still doable with some (most of the time trivial) coding, because the data binding is build around an abstraction called [`PropertyDescriptor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor(v=vs.110).aspx). By default it is implemented via reflection, but nothing prevents you to create your own implementation and do whatever you like inside it. That allows you to do many things that are not possible with reflection, in particular to simulate "properties" that actually do not exist.

Here we will utilize that possibility to create a "property" that actually gets/sets its value from a child property of the original property, while from outside it still looks like a single property, thus allowing to data bind to it:

```
public class ChildPropertyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
{
    public static PropertyDescriptor Create(PropertyDescriptor sourceProperty, string childPropertyPath, string displayName = null)
    {
        var propertyNames = childPropertyPath.Split('.');
        var propertyPath = new PropertyDescriptor[1 + propertyNames.Length];
        propertyPath[0] = sourceProperty;
        for (int i = 0; i < propertyNames.Length; i++)
            propertyPath[i + 1] = propertyPath[i].GetChildProperties()[propertyNames[i]];
        return new ChildPropertyDescriptor(propertyPath, displayName);
    }
    private ChildPropertyDescriptor(PropertyDescriptor[] propertyPath, string displayName)
        : base(propertyPath[0].Name, null)
    {
        this.propertyPath = propertyPath;
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }
    private PropertyDescriptor[] propertyPath;
    private string displayName;
    private PropertyDescriptor RootProperty { get { return propertyPath[0]; } }
    private PropertyDescriptor ValueProperty { get { return propertyPath[propertyPath.Length - 1]; } }
    public override Type ComponentType { get { return RootProperty.ComponentType; } }
    public override bool IsReadOnly { get { return ValueProperty.IsReadOnly; } }
    public override Type PropertyType { get { return ValueProperty.PropertyType; } }
    public override bool CanResetValue(object component) { var target = GetTarget(component); return target != null && ValueProperty.CanResetValue(target); }
    public override object GetValue(object component) { var target = GetTarget(component); return target != null ? ValueProperty.GetValue(target) : null; }
    public override void ResetValue(object component) { ValueProperty.ResetValue(GetTarget(component)); }
    public override void SetValue(object component, object value) { ValueProperty.SetValue(GetTarget(component), value); }
    public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component) { var target = GetTarget(component); return target != null && ValueProperty.ShouldSerializeValue(target); }
    public override AttributeCollection Attributes { get { return ValueProperty.Attributes; } }
    public override string Category { get { return ValueProperty.Category; } }
    public override TypeConverter Converter { get { return ValueProperty.Converter; } }
    public override string Description { get { return ValueProperty.Description; } }
    public override bool IsBrowsable { get { return ValueProperty.IsBrowsable; } }
    public override bool IsLocalizable { get { return ValueProperty.IsLocalizable; } }
    public override string DisplayName { get { return displayName ?? RootProperty.DisplayName; } }
    public override object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType) { return ValueProperty.GetEditor(editorBaseType); }
    public override PropertyDescriptorCollection GetChildProperties(object instance, Attribute[] filter) { return ValueProperty.GetChildProperties(GetTarget(instance), filter); }
    public override bool SupportsChangeEvents { get { return ValueProperty.SupportsChangeEvents; } }
    public override void AddValueChanged(object component, EventHandler handler)
    {
        var target = GetTarget(component);
        if (target != null)
            ValueProperty.AddValueChanged(target, handler);
    }
    public override void RemoveValueChanged(object component, EventHandler handler)
    {
        var target = GetTarget(component);
        if (target != null)
            ValueProperty.RemoveValueChanged(target, handler);
    }
    private object GetTarget(object source)
    {
        var target = source;
        for (int i = 0; target != null && target != DBNull.Value && i < propertyPath.Length - 1; i++)
            target = propertyPath[i].GetValue(target);
        return target != DBNull.Value ? target : null;
    }
}
```

The code is not so small, but all it does is basically delegating the calls to the corresponding methods of the property descriptor chain representing the path from the original property to the child property. Also please note that many methods of the `PropertyDescriptor` are used only during the design time, so creating a custom concrete runtime property descriptor usually needs only to implement [`ComponentType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.componenttype(v=vs.110).aspx), [`PropertyType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.propertytype(v=vs.110).aspx), [`GetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.getvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`SetValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertydescriptor.setvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) (if supported).

So far so good. This is just the first part of the puzzle. We can create a "property", now we need a way to let data binding use it.

In order to do that, we'll utilize another data binding related interface called [`ITypedList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedlist(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Provides functionality to discover the schema for a bindable list, where the properties available for binding differ from the public properties of the object to bind to.

In other words, it allows us to provide "properties" for the list elements. But how? If we were implementing the data source list, it would be easy. But here we want to do that for a list that we don't know in advance (I'm trying the keep the solution generic).

The solutions is to wrap the original list in onother one that will implement `IList` (the minimum requirement for list data binding) by delegating all the calls to the underlying list, but by implementing `ITypedList` will control the properties used for binding:

```
public static class ListDataView
{
    public static IList Create(object dataSource, string dataMember, Func<PropertyDescriptor, PropertyDescriptor> propertyMapper)
    {
        var source = (IList)ListBindingHelper.GetList(dataSource, dataMember);
        if (source == null) return null;
        if (source is IBindingListView) return new BindingListView((IBindingListView)source, propertyMapper);
        if (source is IBindingList) return new BindingList((IBindingList)source, propertyMapper);
        return new List(source, propertyMapper);
    }

    private class List : IList, ITypedList
    {
        private readonly IList source;
        private readonly Func<PropertyDescriptor, PropertyDescriptor> propertyMapper;
        public List(IList source, Func<PropertyDescriptor, PropertyDescriptor> propertyMapper) { this.source = source; this.propertyMapper = propertyMapper; }
        // IList
        public object this[int index] { get { return source[index]; } set { source[index] = value; } }
        public int Count { get { return source.Count; } }
        public bool IsFixedSize { get { return source.IsFixedSize; } }
        public bool IsReadOnly { get { return source.IsReadOnly; } }
        public bool IsSynchronized { get { return source.IsSynchronized; } }
        public object SyncRoot { get { return source.SyncRoot; } }
        public int Add(object value) { return source.Add(value); }
        public void Clear() { source.Clear(); }
        public bool Contains(object value) { return source.Contains(value); }
        public void CopyTo(Array array, int index) { source.CopyTo(array, index); }
        public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { return source.GetEnumerator(); }
        public int IndexOf(object value) { return source.IndexOf(value); }
        public void Insert(int index, object value) { source.Insert(index, value); }
        public void Remove(object value) { source.Remove(value); }
        public void RemoveAt(int index) { source.RemoveAt(index); }
        // ITypedList
        public string GetListName(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors) { return ListBindingHelper.GetListName(source, listAccessors); }
        public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetItemProperties(PropertyDescriptor[] listAccessors)
        {
            var properties = ListBindingHelper.GetListItemProperties(source, listAccessors);
            if (propertyMapper != null)
                properties = new PropertyDescriptorCollection(properties.Cast<PropertyDescriptor>()
                    .Select(propertyMapper).Where(p => p != null).ToArray());
            return properties;
        }
    }

    private class BindingList : List, IBindingList
    {
        private IBindingList source;
        public BindingList(IBindingList source, Func<PropertyDescriptor, PropertyDescriptor> propertyMapper) : base(source, propertyMapper) { this.source = source; }
        private ListChangedEventHandler listChanged;
        public event ListChangedEventHandler ListChanged
        {
            add
            {
                var oldHandler = listChanged;
                if ((listChanged = oldHandler + value) != null && oldHandler == null)
                    source.ListChanged += OnListChanged;
            }
            remove
            {
                var oldHandler = listChanged;
                if ((listChanged = oldHandler - value) == null && oldHandler != null)
                    source.ListChanged -= OnListChanged;
            }
        }
        private void OnListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = listChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, e);
        }
        public bool AllowNew { get { return source.AllowNew; } }
        public bool AllowEdit { get { return source.AllowEdit; } }
        public bool AllowRemove { get { return source.AllowRemove; } }
        public bool SupportsChangeNotification { get { return source.SupportsChangeNotification; } }
        public bool SupportsSearching { get { return source.SupportsSearching; } }
        public bool SupportsSorting { get { return source.SupportsSorting; } }
        public bool IsSorted { get { return source.IsSorted; } }
        public PropertyDescriptor SortProperty { get { return source.SortProperty; } }
        public ListSortDirection SortDirection { get { return source.SortDirection; } }
        public object AddNew() { return source.AddNew(); }
        public void AddIndex(PropertyDescriptor property) { source.AddIndex(property); }
        public void ApplySort(PropertyDescriptor property, ListSortDirection direction) { source.ApplySort(property, direction); }
        public int Find(PropertyDescriptor property, object key) { return source.Find(property, key); }
        public void RemoveIndex(PropertyDescriptor property) { source.RemoveIndex(property); }
        public void RemoveSort() { source.RemoveSort(); }
    }

    private class BindingListView : BindingList, IBindingListView
    {
        private IBindingListView source;
        public BindingListView(IBindingListView source, Func<PropertyDescriptor, PropertyDescriptor> propertyMapper) : base(source, propertyMapper) { this.source = source; }
        public string Filter { get { return source.Filter; } set { source.Filter = value; } }
        public ListSortDescriptionCollection SortDescriptions { get { return source.SortDescriptions; } }
        public bool SupportsAdvancedSorting { get { return source.SupportsAdvancedSorting; } }
        public bool SupportsFiltering { get { return source.SupportsFiltering; } }
        public void ApplySort(ListSortDescriptionCollection sorts) { source.ApplySort(sorts); }
        public void RemoveFilter() { source.RemoveFilter(); }
    }
}
```

Actually as you can see, I've added wrappers for other data source interfaces like `IBindingList` and `IBindingListView`. Again, the code is not so small, but it's just delegating the calls to the underlying objects (when creating one for your concrete data, you usually would inherit from `List<T>` or `BiundingList<T>` and implement only the two `ITypedList` members). The essential part is the [`GetItemProperties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedlist.getitemproperties(v=vs.110).aspx) method implementation which along with the `propertyMapper` lambda allows you to replace one property with another.

With all that in place, solving the specific problem from the post is simple a matter of wrapping the `DataTable` and mapping the `Complex` property to the `Complex.Name` property:

```
class ComplexData
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

class ComplexDataWrapper
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ComplexData Data { get; set; } = new ComplexData();
}

static class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        var form = new Form();
        var gridView = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, Parent = form };
        gridView.DataSource = ListDataView.Create(GetData(), null, p =>
        {
            if (p.PropertyType == typeof(ComplexDataWrapper))
                return ChildPropertyDescriptor.Create(p, "Name", "Complex Name");
            return p;
        });
        Application.Run(form);
    }

    static DataTable GetData()
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Complex", typeof(ComplexDataWrapper));
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            dt.Rows.Add(i, new ComplexDataWrapper { Name = "Name#" + i, Data = new ComplexData { Value = i } });
        return dt;
    }
}
```

To recap, custom `PropertyDescriptor` and `ITypedList` allow you to create unlimited types of views of your data, which then can be used by any data bound aware control.

Answer (score 2):

I believe your architecture is flawed for what you're trying to achieve.

If you are using the gridView to edit a single property on your complex type, then there is no need to bind the entire type into the datatable the is the datasource of your grid.

Instead you should bind only the property you wish to edit, and when the the data comes back, simply assign it to the complex type in the right place.

Comment: Well let me riddle you with this batman, I stumbled across this thread yesterday with hopes of finding an answer to my issue. I have an object with a string for name, and a IEnumerable collection of items. I have to use the list of items to create columns. so Image its  Name of Thing | Column1 (DateTime as header) | Column2  | Column 3 . So the column correspond to the dates of the items, and then the rows will be the items. How would you do that? I tried using a pivot grid but couldn't get it to work the way I had hoped. I ended up creating a custom control to show the data.

Comment: @KevinBBurns From what are you explaining, seems like you should have posted your own question describing your issue. This one is too specific (bidirectional bind to a single nested property), so even if it's solved, I doubt the solution would work for your case.

Comment: @KevinBBurns. I agree with Ivan. Yours is definitely a seperate question. It is a different use case.

Comment: @KevinBBurns.However, I can somewhat answer it for you. You would use a gridview, and you would not autobind the items. Instead you would simply use a loop to iterate over the collection property (not defined but implied to be of DateTime type) and over each item create a column at runtime, then bind before looping again. You should ask a seperate question with more detailed information if you want a more detailed answer.

Comment: I am going to do that actually, I ended up creating a custom control that handles it perfectly. But I was originally binding the "complex" item as a type for the row. And in the View I had created a datatemplate with a label pointing to a property in the object thinking that would work. When I looked at the code, it would just show the name of the object( its default .ToString() function) instead of showing me the bound property. I just assumed DataTables weren't a good way of doing it, I am thinking that I am right.

Comment: @KevinBBurns I agree, you should have no need for an intermediary DataTable. Its a structure that does not represent the structure of your complex type, so dont use it.

Comment: @KevinBBurns Custom presenters (controls) are not necessary in most of the cases. It's all about creating a proper view model of your data. For instance, to model a read only view with dynamic columns, a simple `IList` wrapper, custom `PropertyDescriptor`s and `ITypedList` to expose them would be sufficient. You can take a look at my question [Cross tabular data binding in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32169375/cross-tabular-data-binding-in-wpf)(ignore the answer) for more advanced scenario.